# Циклический редирект в Keycloak

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, openid, keycloak

Всем привет.
Столкнулся с проблемой при добавлении авторизации через Keycloak.

Имеется проект ASPNet MVC Net6.
Keycloak подключен через OpenIdConnect.
Home контроллер я пометил как [Authorize]

После авторизации должна произойти на http://localhost:port/Agents
Но, после успешной авторизации, начинается цикличный редирект.
Вот что я вижу в Networks
[image]

Запросы к кейклоку проходят успешно. С кодом 200.
А вот Agents код 302.
При этом за один цикл идет 2 раза попытка перехода на Agents и 2 запроса в Keycloak.

Код подключения выглядит вот так:

```
 .AddAuthentication(options =>
 {
     options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
 })
 .AddCookie(cookie =>
 {
     cookie.Cookie.Name = "keycloak.cookie";
     cookie.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
     cookie.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
     cookie.SlidingExpiration = true;
 })
  .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
  {
      options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
      options.Authority = "http://localhost:8080/realms/ipn";
      options.ClientId = "IpcpAuth";
      options.ClientSecret = "Tns4Rli7UvsP72pkqqmOrIIBcEG6whVA";

      //options.MetadataAddress = Configuration.GetSection("Keycloak")["Metadata"];  
      //Require keycloak to use SSL  
      options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
      options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
      options.Scope.Add("openid");
      options.Scope.Add("profile");
      options.Scope.Add("email");

      options.SaveTokens = true;
      options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
      options.NonceCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
      options.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
      options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:11059/Agents";
      options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
      {
          NameClaimType = "name",
          RoleClaimType = "https://schemas.scopic.com/roles"
      };
      options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async context =>
      {
          context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "http://localhost:11059/Agents";
          await Task.CompletedTask;
      };}
```

Настройки клиента:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем заключается проблема ?
Пробовал делать чистый проект MVC. Там та же беда. Просто циклическая загрузка страницы и все

Comment: Попробуйте всё то же самое только на https полностью. Используйте самоподписанные сертификаты для локалхоста. А так без подробных логов браузера по редиректам сложно понять, где косяк. Ну и классика - отключить кеш браузера и т.д. Убедитесь что кука встаёт и отправляется серверу.

Comment: @aepot привет. А Keycloak дружит с самоподписными сертификатами? Сделал я jks. Поместил его в standalone.xml, ребутнул контейнер и что-то не видно сертификата :(

Comment: С самоподписанными сертификатами должен дружить не сервер, а браузер.

Comment: @aepot ну  я его из бразуера и не вижу.
Слева от адресной строки есть сообщение, где можно посмотреть сертификат. И там информация о давно стухшем сертификате, а не о новом

Comment: @aepot похоже была проблема с KC. Снес его накатил свежий. 21 версии и самоподписной сертификат встал.
НО... радость была не долгой. Все равно на сертификат что-то ругается :The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors

Comment: Так самоподписка и должна ошибку валидации давать, это нормально. Надо сделать так, чтобы это не было проблемой во время разработки.